# How to add Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Debian 6.0's GRUB?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, debian

I installed Debian because Debian runs better on my PC than Ubuntu.

I installed Debian on an another partition because I wondered to dualboot with Ubuntu.

And after Debian installed, I see in the GRUB menu only:

```
GNU/Linux Debian 2.xx.xxx.xx (or something like this)
GNU/Linux Debian 2.xx.xxx.xx (Recovery mode) (or something like this)
```

And Ubuntu is missing...

Is there any way to add Ubuntu to the GRUB?

[I already Googled, but there's nothing about add Ubuntu to GRUB.]

The Grub version in Debian is:

```
~$ dpkg -l | grep grub
ii grub-common 1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1 GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (common files) 
ii grub-pc 1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1 GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
```

Comment: Did you try to install and run boot-repair.

Comment: Read about Boot Repair here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

If your Debian instalation uses GRUB version 2, then you should just run `update-grub` as root.

If Debian installation uses GRUB version 1, you'll have to edit its `/boot/grub/menu.lst` config file and manually add Ubuntu. Suppose, Ubuntu is on `/dev/sda1`, then the entry will look like this

```
title Ubuntu 12.04
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/grub/core.img
savedefault
boot
```

Comment: There's no menu.lst.
I tried command: nano /boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: In that case, you might want to varify which Grub version is installed by running `dpkg -l | grep grub`. If it's 1.9xx, then it is Grub2, and you should just run the `update-grub` command as root.

Comment: Here's the output:
ii  grub-common                                   1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1         GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (common files)
ii  grub-pc                                       1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1         GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
sebastian@sebastian-desktop:~$

Comment: The update-grub has been worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: Great! I'll add it to the answer above.